# scrollview does not reload it's input views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two buttons in my view, clicking on which I get the corresponding buttons in the scrollview.Both buttons have different data. When I start the app and for the first time click on any button, correct content is shown in scrollview but clicking on the other button does not load the scrollview input views.

Is it not able to reload the data of scrollview or is there any other problem?

Comment: I can assume that you can use setNeedsDisplay method for this, but can you show your code?

Answer (score 0):

Check it select the ScrollView and in Inspector Window select the `Delays Content Touches`
Hope this works.